# Is “bescumber” transitive or intransitive?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, transitive-verbs, transitivity

Behold!

[image: bescumbered]

Did my lawn mower bescumber my neighbor's fence (transitive), or did it bescumber *on* my neighbor's fence (intransitive)?

Or should I switch to passive voice and say my neighbor's fence was bescumbered by my lawn mower, and avoid awkward questions?

Indeed, is it possible to avoid awkward questions at all when discussing bescumbering?

I realize *to bescumber* does not typically involve grass clippings, but I wanted to keep my post reasonably family friendly.

Comment: You would rather wait a couple of days before accepting an answer, so as to give everyone a chance.

Comment: Why should a verb be one and not the other? Aren't many verbs?

Comment: @Kris An answer's having been accepted doesn't prevent new answers from being added.  The accepted answer can be changed if a better one is offered.  And yes, many verbs can be either / or.  If you post an answer expanding your argument, I'll at least upvote it, and will consider accepting it if it's more convincing than tchrist's.

Comment: Weird old words are great. But, to the point, if you passivized your statement involving cumbers and such, the preposition would follow. For example, "My dog  peed on my neighbor's fence" -> "My neighbor's fence was peed _on_ by my dog". 'Besclumpfer' would behave similarly, with on or without.

Comment: @Mitch This works just like the verb which originally in Old English was *bescítan* still works.

Comment: @tchrist Really, I was going to recommend 'beshat on'. No shit.

Comment: I think this is rather a great question, but it would probably be a good idea to mention explicitly in the question itself where you came across the word, and that you do know it’s not exactly common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *To bescumber, to scumber, scummerings, to discumber*

*Becumber* is normally transitive — or at least, can be.

But you shouldn’t use it in casual, non-dialectal speech unless you’re being deliberately and quaintly archaizing. That’s because neither hide nor hair of the word has been seen in nigh unto four centuries. (Wherever did you find it?)

Here’s the OED’s most recent citation:

> - 1631   Ben Jonson *Staple of Newes* v. iv. 62 in *Wks*. II
>   Did Blocke **bescumber** Statutes white suite?

That verb, now marked “*Obsolete*”, is formed from *be-* + *scumber*.

Now, *scumber* meaning to void (feces) can be both transitive or intransitive. The last intransitive citation of it is from forever ago:

> - 1611   J. Davies in T. Coryate *Crudities* sig. i3 
>     And for a *Monument* to *after-commers* Their *Picture* shall continue (though Time ***scummers*** Vpon th’ *Effigie*).
> - 1656   Choyce *Drollery* 37  
>    Beware of fire when you **scumber**.

The transitive citations are much newer, though, ending with:

> - 1819   Keats *Letter to Haydon* 3 Oct.  
>    I have not seen the portentous Book which was **skummer’d** at you just as I left town.
> - 1825   J. Jennings *Observations on some of the Dialects in the West of England, particularly Somersetshire* 69 
>     To *Skummer*, to foul with a dirty liquid, or to daub with soft dirt.

But it too is marked “*obsolete* exc. *dialect.*”, so I wouldn’t suggest it.

It turns out that there’s a nice noun *scummering*, specifically meaning canine excrement, including that of a fox, with a **much** more recent citation:

> 1817   J. Mayer *Sportsman's Direct*. (ed. 2) 203  
>  You may know if it is a good scenting day, by the smoke and strong scent of their **scummerings**.

Alas, this too is marked “*Obsolete*”.

But despair not, for your quest shall not have been in vain! The transitive *discumber* is ***Not Obsolete***, having been spotted within living memory.  It means:

> 1. *trans*. To relieve of a burden, impediment, or encumbrance; to disencumber. Frequently with *of, from*. Now *rare*.

Here’s a recent citation:

> - 1987   *Historia* 36 93  
>    They had **discumbered** themselves of Hermes Aerios and his keeper.

Congratulations, you get a less scatological version you can use that’s merely rare and not obsolete. Yay?

---

<sub>**Ethical Disclosure:** No cucumbers were discumbered nor becumbered in the production of this answer, despite the pictured ***wall-besplattered scummerings’*** aroma to the contrary.</sub>

Comment: The time is ripe for a resurrection of the word.  I recently read it in "The Way of Kings" by Brandon Sanderson.  Unfortunately, the book doesn't provide a proper example of the word, but merely asks, "I say, do you know any words that rhyme with bescumber?"  In any case, thank you for your outstanding, well-researched answer.  I regret that I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: @rojo Then you should certainly submit that citation to the OED. They’ll love it. And the answer to the riddle is of course that *discumber* rhymes with *bescumber*. Then again, so does *his number*.

Comment: It's a shame people are downvoting this answer.  They are certainly not doing so based on its content.  The english.stackexchange.com culture is a strange one.  Re: submitting the citation to OED, I will once I figure out how.

Comment: @rojo Wit, I presume?

Comment: @terdon Correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Be`scum´ber](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Bescumber)
v. **t.**   1.  To discharge ordure or dung upon.

Comment: Never bring a knife to a gunfight.

Comment: @tchrist - My point is that the definition (from Websters) says that the word is transitive.  This is unambiguous, and the question should be closed due to the OP's failure to do research.

Comment: If *that* was your point, ’twould appear you’ve hit the wrong button, for posting an answer no close vote casts. :)

Comment: @tchrist - If you look, there's a close vote.

Comment: So there is. Did you both close vote ***and*** answer, then? Really? Don’t be surprised if someone takes you to task a bit for that one.

Comment: @tchrist Why do you think so? Should people **stop** doing so henceforth upon learning of it now?

Comment: @Kris tchrist has a valid point. If a question is going to be closed, then why bother posting an answer? And if a question is worthy of an answer, why vote to close it?

Comment: @HotLicks Original content is crucial for an online community to succeed. As long as questions aren't duplicated, new posts shouldn't be discouraged, regardless of their ease of answering. The autistic culture on this site discourages healthy discourse and new user interest, and ought to be re-evaluated. There's a reason StackOverflow has tags with nearly a million watchers, whereas english.stackexchange.com struggles to reach 300 on its busiest tag. Without my poorly researched question, we would never have seen tchrist's outstanding, well-researched and well-organized answer.

Comment: @rojo - One of the goals of this site is to teach users how to effectively use resources so that they don't have to ask for help with every other word.  There are times of the year when the site is swamped by "What does X mean?" questions, and answering them with quotes from a readily-available online dictionary is not a productive use of anyone's time.  And, perhaps more importantly, questions of this sort are just "noise" to the many people who come here hoping to actually LEARN something.

Comment: @rojo   tchrist is perfectly capable of arguing his own case and needs no advocates. No offense. Also, it is obvious you are not in touch with the FAQ.